How can I write a hook to modify the workflow of a parent class using parameters from parametrize in pytest?
The question: How can I do some extra actions within a parent class that set ups my tests with an autouse fixture?
Context with reproducible example:

I have a class that I use as parent class for many test cases called BaseTestClass.
This class BaseTestClass contains a fixture with an autouse fixture generate_test_preamble which contains a hook do_something_hook which is override by the child class which contains the test.
The test class is TestSomething which is the child class of BaseTestClass.
The test class takes multiple parameters some_parametrized_variable.
I want to make use of those parameters within the hook.

My attempt:

I tried with another autouse fixture to use those parameters and save them within the class with the fixture set_class_value_fixture.
Then I expected the value to be set withing the autouse fixture.

Problem:

It seems the fixture is not setting the class variable before the hook of the other autouse fixture is executed:


E       AttributeError: 'TestSomething' object has no attribute 'my_class_variable'

Reproducible example code:
"""
Test
"""

from typing import override
import pytest


class BaseTestClass:
    """
    Some base class with autouse fixture that executes something before the test. This class should
    not be altered as it is used by many tests
    """

    def do_something_hook(self):
        """
        This can be override
        """

    @pytest.fixture(scope="function", name="generate_test_preamble", autouse=True)
    def generate_test_preamble(self):
        """
        Autouse common to many tests
        """
        self.do_something_hook()
        print("Generating data...")


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "some_parametrized_variable",
    [
        "a",
        "b",
    ],
)
class TestSomething(BaseTestClass):
    """
    My test class with many parameters that alter the base class
    """

    my_class_variable: str

    @pytest.fixture(
        scope="function",
        name="set_class_value_fixture",
        autouse=True,
    )
    def set_class_value_fixture(self, some_parametrized_variable: str) -> None:
        """
        "Hack" to be able to have access from the class to the parameters of the test
        """
        print(f"Setting: {some_parametrized_variable}")
        self.my_class_variable = some_parametrized_variable

    @override
    def do_something_hook(self):
        """
        Implement the hook with access to the parameters
        """
        print(f"From hook: {self.my_class_variable}")

    def test_a(self) -> None:
        """
        main
        """
        print("Running main test")
        print(f"My variable is: {self.my_class_variable}")

NOTE: Adding the fixture of set_class_value_fixture as dependency in the parent should not be an option, as that is a property for only the child test.
